# AWS EC2: EBS snapshot without reboot in read only context it is safe (consistent)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, snapshot

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 EC2 instance on AWS platform, with 2 EBS volume attached, the first (C:) for Windows SO (root volume) and the second (D:) for static file storage served by http server.

During the day, some file are read and write on D:\ but during the night the files are only read (no create/update files).

If during the night (in read only context) i make a EBS snapshot of D:\ without reboot (for backup purpose), the snapshot is safe/consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually re-mounting the filesystem as read-only? If so, then yes, the filesystem will be in a consistent state.

If, though, by "read only" you mean that there are few (or no) writes, there are still no guarantees that the filesystem will be in a consistent state. It's likely that it will work, though, but as I said, no guarantees.

Comment: it's the second choise, and i'm sure there aren't  write operation. What happens if the snapshot isn't consistent? Can i re-mount it?

Comment: a inconsistent snapshot can be remounted?

Comment: Since the filesystem will be in an inconsistent state, the OS will want to do a filesystem check before mounting. This will identify filesystem issues, but unless your filesystem is truly unmounted cleanly before the snapshot, file corruption can never be 100% ruled out.

Comment: sorry, i have another question (the last one) :D
Do you know how long is downtime of ec2 instance for create a snapshot?

Comment: It depends on too many factors for me to give you good information about that. Test it on your setup and find out.